# How can i make popup message in odoo?

Tags: forms, popup, default, odoo

My goal is:

- Open form view
- if field value
- display popup message

How to do? I'm using:

```py
@api.model
    def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        res = super(SaleOrder, self).fields_view_get(
            view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
```

function but not working on me. Help, I need any solution?

Comment: Use `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `raise` to show a pop-up.

Example:

```py
def sample_method(self):
    raise (_('Header!'), _('Message.'))
```

Hope it will help you.